# Help center's "what is on topic" is unclear to outsiders

Tags: bug

I have a certain question, and was unsure if it would be on topic at Sound Design. To be a good citizen, I checked [the appropriate Help Center topic](https://sound.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but this defines "Sound Design" using the term... "Sound Design", which isn't very helpful:

> **What topics can I ask about here?**
>
> As long as your question involves sound design and is:
>
> - detailed and specific
> - written clearly and simply
> - of interest to at least one other person interested in sound design
>
> ... it is welcome here.

I'm an outsider, please assume in that I don't (exactly) know what "Sound Design" means or what it includes.

---

<sub>As a *foot note*, specifically, I was wondering if questions about audio cables and connecting media devices to speaker sets would be on topic or not. My guess was that it would *not* be on topic, which is why I tried checking the FAQ first.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Most probably that isn't on topic. We are working on improving the definition but it isn't done yet. In general consumer targeted stuff is off topic though.